# PostgreSQL: Sorting letters before numbers

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by

I would like to order a bpchar column in the following order (first order by a-z, then numbers):

```
abc
bcd     
xrf/1     
zyd   
0/abc
0/bdc   
0/efg
```

How could I accomplish that?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't fully tell from your question what you actually want. If it is the first character of the string you want to check whether it's numeric or alphabet, you may use a `CASE` expression in `ORDER BY` like this.

```
select * FROM t ORDER BY
          CASE 
             WHEN col ~ '^[a-zA-Z]' THEN 1
             WHEN col ~ '^[0-9]'    THEN 2
           END,col;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=e25536ae2d5bd487e8301eaea4d91551)